# Getting an object back when I should get a string

Tags: php, forms, element

So I wrote a basic class which I have extended to create html element. Based on Zend - HOWEVER not exactly. **No this is not a question about or in relation to zend**

```
class AisisCore_Form_Elements_Input extends AisisCore_Form_Element {

    protected $_html = '';

    public function init(){

        foreach($this->_options as $options){
            $this->_html .= '<input type="text" ';

            if(isset($options['id'])){
                $this->_html .= 'id="'.$options['id'].'" ';
            }

            if(isset($options['class'])){
                $this->_html .= 'class="'.$options['class'].'" ';
            }

            if(isset($options['attributes'])){
                foreach($options['attributes'] as $attrib){
                    $this->_html .= $attrib;
                }
            }

            $this->_html .= $this->_disabled;
            $this->_html .= ' />';

            return  $this->_html;
        }
    }
}
```

so this class extends my element class which consists of a constructor that takes in an array of options, a basic element is set up as such:

```
$array_attrib = array(
    'attributes' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Test'
    )
);

$element = new AisisCore_Form_Elements_Input($array_attrib);
echo $element;
```

So what's the problem?

echoing the $element object gives me an error saying it cant convert the object to a string, thus when I var_dump it I get this back:

```
object(AisisCore_Form_Elements_Input)#21 (3) {
  ["_html":protected]=>
  string(22) "<input type="text"  />"
  ["_options":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["placeholder"]=>
      string(4) "Test"
    }
  }
  ["_disabled":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

Can some one explain what's going on? Last I checked I was echoing out a string not an object. How did I manage to create an object?

If you need to see the AisisCore_Form_Element class I will post it how ever all this class is a base class you extend to create the element. the only thing it takes is an array of options.

Comment: not the solution... but why the `return()` inside your foreach? That'll just kill the foreach on the first iteration.

Comment: oh thats probably my fault, it should be out side the foreach >.< early morning coding

Comment: It's giving you back an object because you set `$element` to a new instance of the `AisisCode_Form_Elements_Input` class. If you want to be able to echo a string from an object variable, you'd need to use the magic `__toString` method. Have I missed something?

Comment: i have never heard of that before.....Are you sure? I am looking at __toString Doc now

Comment: @KyleAdams, check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your constructor was trying to return a value (in the middle of the for loop as well), when you probably wanted to something like this....

```
class AisisCore_Form_Elements_Input extends AisisCore_Form_Element {

    protected $_html = '';

    public function init(){

        foreach($this->_options as $options){
            $this->_html .= '<input type="text" ';

            if(isset($options['id'])){
                $this->_html .= 'id="'.$options['id'].'" ';
            }

            if(isset($options['class'])){
                $this->_html .= 'class="'.$options['class'].'" ';
            }

            if(isset($options['attributes'])){
                foreach($options['attributes'] as $attrib){
                    $this->_html .= $attrib;
                }
            }

            $this->_html .= $this->_disabled;
            $this->_html .= ' />';

            // Constructors Don't Return Values - this is wrong
            //return  $this->_html;
        }
    }

    // provide a getter for the HTML
    public function getHtml()
    {
         return $this->_html;
    }
}
```

Now your example can be updated to look like this...

```
$element = new AisisCore_Form_Elements_Input($array_attrib);
echo $element->getHtml();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to echo an instance, not a string.
you even var_dumped it and saw clearly that this is an object.. not a string.

if you wish you to be able to use the instance as a string, you must implement the __toString
method within your class.

note that the method __toString MUST return a string.

good luck.